# MS Access compare two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, comparison

I have two tables I am comparing sales by representative, TY vs LY. While comparing both tables I have new representatives this year and representatives that left the company last year.

When I run my query I only get results for representatives that are still with the company. I want all, any suggestions on how to go by doing this? I have tried creating a table with all the reps names and creating ac connection but that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concepts in [Creating an outer join query in Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/creating-an-outer-join-query-in-access-HA001034555.aspx)?

Comment: I am not! This is great information. Ill research this more, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all Sales Reps from both tables then you'll want to use an OUTER JOIN. Unfortunately, Access SQL does not support the FULL OUTER JOIN construct directly, so you'll need to simulate it through the UNION of two LEFT JOINs.

For example, given the tables [LY]...

```
SalesRep  TotalSales
--------  ----------
OldGuy          3000
SameGuy         5000
```

...and [TY]...

```
SalesRep  TotalSales
--------  ----------
NewGuy          2000
SameGuy         6000
```

...the query

```sql
    SELECT 
        TY.SalesRep, 
        TY.TotalSales AS TY_Sales,
        Nz(LY.TotalSales, 0) AS LY_Sales
    FROM
        TY LEFT JOIN LY ON TY.SalesRep = LY.SalesRep
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        LY.SalesRep, 
        0 AS TY_Sales,
        LY.TotalSales AS LY_Sales
    FROM
        LY LEFT JOIN TY ON TY.SalesRep = LY.SalesRep
    WHERE TY.SalesRep IS NULL
```

returns

```
SalesRep  TY_Sales  LY_Sales
--------  --------  --------
NewGuy        2000         0       
SameGuy       6000      5000    
OldGuy           0      3000
```